# How to create list of localStorage item in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have error with localStorage stored values i got result like this ["john","smith", "sharik", "this is stored value"]

but i want each item in new line without any semicolon or brackets.

i want like this:-

1. john
2. smith
3. sharik
4. this is stored value

how can i achieve that please help me below my codes->

```
$(".searchsome").on("click",function search(e) {
addEntry();
var entry = localStorage.getItem("allEntrie");
for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
$(".showSearchData").append('<p class="keywordsOnDiv">' + entry[i] + '</p>');
});

function addEntry() {
var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntrie"));
if(existingEntries == null) existingEntries = [];
var entryTitle = $(".searchsome").val();
localStorage.setItem("entrys", entryTitle);
existingEntries.push(entryTitle);
localStorage.setItem("allEntrie",existingEntries);
};
```

here my code please hrlp me to get all stored name with new line and without semicolon and brackets Thanks StackOverFlow.

Comment: `existingEntries.join("\n")`

Comment: `["john","smith", "sharik", "this is stored value"]` is a string or array?

Comment: where can i use this line?

Comment: it is a array @brk

Comment: but `localStorage.getItem("allEntrie")` will give a string not an array

Comment: Use `.join(_S_)` to convert array to string seperated by `_S_`, so to store it in localStorage use `localStorage.setItem("allEntrie",existingEntries.join("\n"));`

Comment: sorry sorry sir it is a sting sorry for mistake @brk

Answer (score 0):

If the value stored in localStorage is like `'["john","smith", "sharik", "this is stored value"]'`

then use `JSON.parse` at this line

```
var entry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allEntrie"));
for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i++) {
$(".showSearchData").append('<p class="keywordsOnDiv">' + entry[i] + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: its dividing each word into new line not dividing to each item

Comment: what you mean by `each item`

Comment: each item mean like smith, sharik,john and all

Comment: Thank you very much @brk finally i got my result through you thanks

Comment: @Equaltomultiply happy to help

Comment: input on focus create all keyword again and again but i want only on first time focus show all keyword otherwise show only created keyword

Answer (score 0):

Try the below it's simple search bar which stores keys in `localStorage`, but make sure you removed `var localStorage = {};` as it just for testing on Stackoverflow.

This will get stored data from `localStorage` as array and convert it back to string after adding the new item and store it again.

```js
function addEntry(v) {
  //------------------------
  var localStorage = {}; // <--- remove this line
  //------------------------


  var existingEntries = JSON.parse(localStorage["allEntrie"] || "[]");
  existingEntries.push(v);
  localStorage["entrys"] = v;
  localStorage["allEntrie"] = JSON.stringify(existingEntries);
  return v;
};

$(".searchsome").on("keyup", function() {
  var v = this.value.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();
  $(".showSearchData").prepend('<p class="keywordsOnDiv">' + addEntry(v) + '</p>');
});
```

```css
p {
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="searchsome" />
<div class="showSearchData">
  <div>
```